# If condition on user input

Tags: python, windows

I want to if put condition on inputs like if i want to print a particular result on a particular input
like if user inputs (set my number 3 ) then the result should be printed like (xbox is good but playstation is best ) and is user inputs (set my number 55) then result should be (an apple a day keeps the doctor away)
i cant put the if condition on inputs please help

I want program to do this

```
num1 = raw_input ("num1> ")
num1 = num1.split(" ")[-1]
print("num of apples => "+str(num1));sleep(0.01)
```

I want to do it like if user inputs (" I want 2 apples")the result should be different and if user types I want 3 mangoes the result should be different.
Inputs will be same like user will only ask for apples or mangoes it is the number of apples and mangoes that will change so I want to predefine the results for apples and mangoes what can i do. And I can't put if conditions on my code I am a noob please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to clearly think about what you want the program to do. think of it this way, as your code will run sequentially , you have to get the user input data and then process it. for example as you want to know about number of apples, you check the sentece for existing , for example:

```
if 'apple' in num1:
    if '3' in num1:
        print "he wants 3 apples"
```

as if you wanted to extract the numbers, checkout the str.isdigit() method

Comment: Look after your suggestion I am getting plenty of errors. My code is `num1 = raw_input ("what do you want")
if 'apple' is in num1:
    if '3' is in num1:
    print ("he wants 3 apples")`
    if 'apple' is in num1:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your code worked after removing 'is' from the line. if 'apple' is in num1:. I corrected it by removing is. And now it's working thanks

Comment: @Whoami , yeah, i didn't think it through before sending it, fixed it, thanks

Comment: @Whoami mark the question as solved if it did cover your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is your question. From what I understand, this should at least help you to start:

```
inp = input("What is the number?")
if int(inp) == 3:
    ## do something
elif int(inp) == 5:
    ## do something
```

Comment: In my case user doesn't just inputs the number but rather it inputs a sentence. Like instead inputting 3, user inputs this ("I want 3 apples") and then I wanted program to automatically recognize that user wants apple and there are 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Considering everything will remain same except the number and fruit name, we can make a very **ugly and question-specific** solution.

Here it goes:

```
s = input().strip()[7:]
index = s.find(' ')
n = int(s[0:index])
fruit = s[index:].strip()
```

Now given your input, `n` has the number and fruit has the `fruit` name.

Now we can go on and do something like

```
if fruit == "apples":
    print("He needs "+ str(n)+ " red fruits")
if fruit == "mangoes":
    print("He needs "+ str(n)+ " yellow fruits")
```

**Edit**:  This will only work with inputs which starts with `"I want "` followed by a number, and finally followed by a fruit name.